# AngularJS ng-click() is not working in dynamic call by .append(' ') function in controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IARL0.png)I am trying to append HTML elements dynamically which have AngularJS `ng-click`, but it’s not working. I have tried `{{2+2}}` in `iEl.append(<div>{{2+2}}<div>)`,
but it’s not working.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$scope.appendContent = function() {
    var iEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#med2' ) );

    iEl.append('<div class="row well"  ng-controller=Directive id="med1"> <div class="col-sm-12"  > <p>Medication {{2+2}}</p> <div class="col-sm-4"> Medicine <div class="well" dragular="{"classes":{"mirror":"custom-green-mirror"},"nameSpace":"same"}"></div> </div> <div class="col-sm-3"> Frequency <div class="well" dragular="{"classes":{"mirror":"custom-green-mirror"},"nameSpace":"same"}"></div> </div> <div class="col-sm-4"> Days <div class="well" dragular="{"classes":{"mirror":"custom-green-mirror"},"nameSpace":"same"}" ng-click=appendContent()></div> </div> <div class="col-sm-1"> <button class="close cursorDefault" ng-click="removeDIV()">X</button> </div> </div>');
};
```

I want html view like this, auto append when ever fill the value.

Comment: You are doing it wrong.. Totally. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I believe directives and binding equations must be present in the DOM when AngularJS bootstraps the page. Also, as it's already been commented, doing this kind of DOM manipulation in not a very good approach when using AngularJS. It is not in the correct paradigm.

Comment: I want to append this iE.append("  ");
its working fine but , angularjs ng-click() is not working.
Actually, I want append in view which is again append the same html elements.

Answer (score 0):

Never manipulate the DOM in Angular if it can be avoided (except if you're in a directive). Instead of using `querySelector` and `angular.element`, you should use an `ng-repeat` directive tag inside of your `#med2` tag in your HTML (and you could probably remove the id if it isn't used elsewhere). This `ng-repeat` tag would include the HTML that's current in your JavaScript string (which should not be in your JavaScript source anyway). Then, when `appendContent` is called, instead of appending HTML to the element directly, you should append an object to an array that represents the underlying data controlled by `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

use :

$scope.appendContent = function() 
{

$scope.$apply(function () {

```
    var iEl = document.getElementById('med2');
    iEl.append('content')
```

});

}